# AWS PHP SDK - Check if file exists

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Getting very frustrated here. I am trying to check whether a file in my bucket exists or not via PHP <> AWS S3 call. There are 3 ways of doing so and not one seems to work for me.

The keys, credentials, bucket names, filepath and filename are all correct, but no error and simply no result for all 3 options.

```
// Setup AWS SDK for S3
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('mykey', 'mysecret');
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => "latest",
    'region'  => "ap-southeast-1",
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
// check if connection was successful
if (!$s3) {
    echo 'There was an error connecting to AWS S3 SDK';
}

// // option 1
$check_file = $s3->getObjectInfo('my.server.public', '/reports/ihg_seak/images/banner_' . $property_id . '.png');
if ($check_file) {
    $banner_image = 'banner_' . $property_id;
    $summary_image = 'summary_' . $property_id;
} else {
    $banner_image = 'banner_00';
    $summary_image = 'summary_00';
}

// option 2
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
$filename = 's3://my.server.public/reports/ihg_seak/images/banner_' . $property_id . '.png';
$check_file = file_exists($filename);
if ($check_file) {
    $banner_image = 'banner_'.$property_id;
    $summary_image = 'summary_'.$property_id;
} else {
    $banner_image = 'banner_00';
    $summary_image = 'summary_00';
}

// option 3
$check_file = $s3->doesObjectExist('my.server.public', '/reports/ihg_seak/images/banner_' . $property_id . '.png');
if ($check_file) {
    $banner_image = 'banner_' . $property_id;
    $summary_image = 'summary_' . $property_id;
} else {
    $banner_image = 'banner_00';
    $summary_image = 'summary_00';
}
```

Can anyone advise why I am not getting any response at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#headobject)

This should give either 200 OK or 404 NOT FOUND depending on whether file exists at that particular location.

You can also check the permissions of IAM user. It should have GetObject permission.

HeadObject is also accessible from AWS CLI. That is quite helpful if you want to make sure if the problem lies with the code or elsewhere.